# text goes through css div

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why is the "red"-text going through the div at the bottom, when I make the window very small?

jsfiddle.net/cdraT/

Comment: @satinder Why have you changed my layout to make it work? Where is the width fixed of left css div and where are the scrollbars vertical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent this behavior you could add `overflow: hidden` to the div so you would get something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/cdraT/5/

That is if I understood your issue correctly :-)

**EDIT**

With vertical scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/cdraT/6/

Comment: but I need both vertical scrollbars.

Comment: @Pascal sorry I need glasses :) Updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now define your red box `min-height:100%;` and remove `height :100%`

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdraT/1/)

Comment: does not work in my IE9. The red color div does a line break when the window is very scrollbar so the red div shows a vertical scrollbar.